# How to create a ProgressBar programmatically?

Tags: android, android-progressbar

My application needs to create a small `ProgressBar` programmatically.
`ProgressBar` doesn't have a method to set the style (I want a small
`ProgressBar`). The constructor can take an `AttributeSet`, however, it is an
interface and requires me to implement a set of functions. Is there a way
to set the `ProgressBar` to a small style? (I can't use XML to create
`ProgressBar`.)

Answer (score 180, accepted):

Most of the time if you provide an `AttributeSet` manually you have to use one of Android's.  Luckily, they've exposed the attribute set that describes a small progress bar.  Use this code:

```
progressBar = new ProgressBar(activity, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleSmall);
```

Comment: This makes the progressbar look yelowish and old instead of the thin blue (newish) one.

Comment: @kilaka  just for future reference, change the android.R.attr.progressBarStyleSmall to android.R.attr.progressBarStyleHorizontal for the newish one :)

Comment: @BabyGorilla And does progressBarStyleHorizontal work on all of android version?!

Comment: Will 'progressBarStyleSmall' this style supports in mdpi devices ??

Comment: @Neil Traft
I tried this code, but didn't work. So, Shall I call anything else to show it?

Comment: @AbdulhamidDhaiban You have to add your `ProgressBar` to a `ViewGroup` like `LinearLayout`, then only it will appear on the screen.

Answer (score 12):

Create a layout xml file in res/layout directory with desired progress bar containig all attributes you need:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ProgressBar
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" ... />
```

Next in the Activity class you can create ProgressBar object from that layout:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    ProgressBar bar = (ProgressBar ) inflater.inflate(R.layout.small_progress_bar, null);
```

where R.layout.small_progress_bar links to your layout xml file.

Can you still not use xml file?

Comment: Instead of inflating manually, you can setYour contentview to this progressbar and change the layout once your data are loded.

Answer (score 0):

**Activity.java**

```
  progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
 `progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`// To Show ProgressBar 
 `progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` //To Hide ProgressBar
```

[image]

**Check here** 
[ProgressDialog is deprecated.What is the alternate one to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45373007/progressdialog-is-deprecated-what-is-the-alternate-one-to-use/45613741#45613741)

Comment: Not sure, but does the progressBar run always in background(just hidden from the UI) after making it invisible?

Comment: @Shambhu hi,,,yes it will be run in background...but if you make **View.GONE** it will not run in background as well foreground because object is removed...i hope this may help you