# How to make Android ProgressBar determinate in code?

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I'm trying to do add a progressbar in code and make it determinate:

```
progressBar = new ProgressBar(getActivity());
progressBar.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
parent.addView(progressBar, index);
progressBar.setId(id.list_item_secondary);
progressBar.setProgressDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(drawable.progress_horizontal));
progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
progressBar.setMax(100);
```

After `progressBar.setIndeterminate(false)`, `isIndeterminate` is still true and the progress keeps shows the indeterminate circle.

**How can I make it determinate?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the ProgressBar source code [here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/ProgressBar.java), the constructor you are calling is in line 237 which is calling the constructor in line 241 which in turn calls the constructor in line 245 with the style:

```
com.android.internal.R.attr.progressBarStyle
```

This style has the attribute android:indeterminateOnly set to true by default so your calls to setIndeterminate are ignored. See the function description at line 433.

I haven't done this but I assume that if you call the constructor in line 245 like this:

```
progressBar = new ProgressBar(getActivity(), null, <Your Style ID>);
```

passing as the third parameter a style definition with android:indeterminateOnly to false it should work. Based in the source code I assume that setIndeterminate is there only to enable it and not to disable it.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Do you know of a such a style in Android's framework?

Comment: @kilaka I think that android.R.style.Widget_ProgressBar_Horizontal will do the job...

Comment: It wasn't enough. I had to set the progress drawable: `progressBar.setProgressDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.progress_horizontal))`

Comment: Summarizing: indeterminateOnly is set by default to true, which prevents from changing to determinate. This can be changed only by a style, which is set only in the constructor.

Comment: Side note: The line numbers you wrote above are different from one Android version to another. You are referencing the master branch. A lot of phones aren't running the master but one of the release branches. Also, the master can change and you line numbers won't be relevant any more.

Comment: Also, even when providing with a newer, built-in, style (`Widget_Holo_Light_ProgressBar_Horizontal`), the progress looks yellowish and old. Here's the drawables needed for the new, blueish, look: http://ppl.ug/cAHLkaL7aic/. Just put it in the drawable-xhdpi folder and reference to it: `drawable.progress_horizontal_holo_light`. Enjoy.

Comment: Link no more aviable @AlikElzin-kilaka...

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you are setting the ProgressBar's style attribute. From [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#setIndeterminate%28boolean%29) for `setIndeterminate()`:

> If this progress bar's style only supports indeterminate mode (such as the circular progress bars), then this will be ignored.

You should manually set the style e.g. via `style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"`. Simply changing the `Drawable` isn't enough.

Comment: So how do I set the progressbar's style?

Comment: You can set it in the constructor, like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3765577/752320

Comment: Better yet, use `style="?android:progressBarStyleHorizontal"` to pick up the theme's given style.

Answer (score 0):

Your default ProgressBar style has android:indeterminateOnly set to true. So you cant change ProgressBar's indeterminate state. [source code.](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.0_r1/android/widget/ProgressBar.java#ProgressBar.setIndeterminate%28boolean%29)

Comment: So how can I make it determinate?

Comment: Have you seen source? There is no way ) Use correct style in constructor. @Geobits is right.

Answer (score -1):

Try also using `setProgress()`, which takes an integer argument between zero and `getMax()`.

Comment: Already tried it. Didn't work. Why do you think this should work?