# Custom progressbar is always in indeterminate mode and shows up as a square

Tags: android, progress-bar

I am trying to use a custom progress bar however it is stuck in indeterminate mode even when I set it to false, and the progressbar is a square. When I supply the width and height for the layoutparams, the width of the bar does not match the width I set, instead it matches the height, making the progressbar a square.

Here is the code:

```
    ProgressBar pbRightExtruder = new ProgressBar(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lpProgressBar = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lpProgressBar.weight = 1;
    pbRightExtruder.setLayoutParams(lpProgressBar);
    pbRightExtruder.setProgress(50);
    pbRightExtruder.setIndeterminate(false);
    pbRightExtruder.setIndeterminateDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.progressbar));
    pbRightExtruder.setProgressDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.progressbar));
    layoutRightExtruder.addView(pbRightExtruder);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: you need three args ctor, with last arg set to android.R.attr. progressBarStyleHorizontal

Answer (score 0):

if you are useing `weight` then set `width` to 0 instead of `LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT`. Then the `weight` will work properlly. For `indeterminate` problem see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17790923/how-to-make-android-progressbar-determinate-in-code).